# Databricks SQL Server connection across multiple notebooks

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, databricks

I found some [resources](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/12276/how-to-pass-variable-from-one-notebook-to-another.html) for how to pass variables across pySpark databricks notebooks. I'm curious if we can pass SQL Server connection, such as having host/database/port/user/pw in Notebook A and calling the connection on Notebook B.

Comment: does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at that part of Databricks documentation: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#pass-structured-data.
This way you can pass strings, one or multiple, across notebooks, but you'll have to create the connection in Notebook B manually.

Other option - create Notebook A, that creates a connection variable, and "run" it before executing some code in Notebook B (more details here - https://forums.databricks.com/questions/154/can-i-run-one-notebook-from-another-notebook.html). Basically, you need a cell with code:

```
%run path/to/notebookA
```

Comment: I haven't been to get it to work for SQL connection. I get error "Failed to parse %run commad: string matching regex..." . My SQL connection keys and strings are in NotebookA. & Using your code in NotebookB @Rayan Ral

Comment: cell with this code should have only this %run command, and nothing else. Please make sure there's no other code in that cell.

Comment: Im not sure it works for sql connection strings. It does work for functions though. Are you familiar w/ Databricsk dbutils.notebook.exit?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290836/databricks-dbutils-notebook-exit @Rayan Ral

Comment: Failed to parse %run command: string matching regex `\$[\w_]+' expected but `V' found) Stacktrace: /Users/abc@abc/version2: python @Rayan Ral